# Light stable browser for Windows

Tags: windows, web-browser

I am looking for a Lightweight and  stable browser for Windows 10.
It should use a minimum of resources with a few windows or tabs, and launch fast.
I have tried K-Melon and Midori, but they crashed.

This is for an old computer used as a server, on which I sometimes have to use a browser for local webapps on the machine or routers for example.
(Generally not very complex sites, rendering doesn't have to be very good and no flash or similar  plugins needed).

I might also use it as default browser on other PCs, so that everything calling the default browsers opens fast.  (Not really as main browser)

Comment: Related: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12025/minimalist-web-browser-no-tabs-no-plugins-no-bookmarks

Answer (score 4):

[Pale Moon](https://www.palemoon.org/)

It is Firefox based. I've tried many Firefox and Chromium based browsers and Pale Moon is my favourite out of all of them. It's much lighter than Firefox. Finding addons compatible with Firefox 25 may be a bit hard, but all you have to do is search within Firefox addon version history list and find ones compatible with Firefox 25. I use my favourite addons in Pale Moon portable on a flash disk wherever I go.

*EDIT*

Almost forgot about [Memory Fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/memory-fox-next/), an addon for Firefox. Even though it hasn't been updated for such a long time it does help Firefox reduce some RAM usage. Pretty handy if you use a few resource hungry addons.

Comment: Note: Memory Fox is no longer available on AMO.

Answer (score 0):

What about tring some text-based browser?
Here is list:

1. W3M
2. Elinks
3. Lynx
4. Links
5. Links2

other...

Sorry for answer without links.